# GMT+5.30 string convert to Date in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

As per below [LINK](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements004.htm#sthref377),
I try to convert my string `'Tue May 24 20:11:20 GMT+05:30 2011'` to date in oracle

```
select TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('Tue May 24 20:11:20 GMT+05:30 2011', 'DY MON DD HH24:MI:SS  TZDTZH:TZM YYYY') from dual;
```

But it's throw the error

```
ORA-01857: not a valid time zone 
01857. 00000 - "not a valid time zone"
```

Please guide me how to convert with `GMT` Zone Name in Date conversion.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think GMT has any significance here. Since, +5:30 always means it is relative to GMT, you can remove GMT from your string and then convert.

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ (
          REPLACE ('Tue May 24 20:11:20 GMT+05:30 2011', 'GMT'),
          'DY MON DD HH24:MI:SS TZH:TZM YYYY')
  FROM DUAL;
```

Or,

You can do this also, by putting GMT in double quotes.

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ (
          'Tue May 24 20:11:20 GMT+05:30 2011',
          'DY MON DD HH24:MI:SS "GMT"TZH:TZM YYYY')
  FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: I can't do it because that value come from other source of database. I did it this conversion without "GMT". If possible give me solution with "GMT". Otherwise I don't need this answer.

Comment: Till GMT is not appear in output..Your Query Output
 TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('TUEMAY2420:11:20GMT+05:302011','DYMONDDHH24:MI:SS"GMT"TZH:TZMYYYY')
 5/24/2011 8:11:20.000000000 PM +05:30

Comment: Why do you want GMT in your output. When you use to_timestamp_tz, you are converting a string to timestamp with timezone type. It will have date, time and timezone details in it. When you want to display, you should use to_char.

Comment: Because If I modified the value then it's point to temparing value. In other product's database it's store in string and for the report I need to convert into date.

Comment: 1. You are not at all tampering the value. You are just converting a string to `timestamp with timezone ` type.  2. If you want to use it in report, why convert in the first place? Why not directly use the string?

Comment: That is different problem. Is it possible or not in oracle? Because TZD return the timezone name why it's not applicable here.

Comment: I think oracle accepts timezone names and not abbreviations. I have answered your question of converting string to timestamp. You are assuming there is a problem, when there is no problem at all. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/28090